# Bootstrap 5: When i clicked my button, the color changed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Im using bootstrap button, then i changed the color of the button. but when i clicked the button it change to blue, even though i write `.btn-primary:active`

**HTML:**

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">My Button</button>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #ffa500;
  border: 1px solid #e39400;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #e39400;
  border: 1px solid #e39400;
}

.btn-primary:active {
  background-color: #e39400;
  border: 1px solid #e39400;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `!imporant` and it should work

```css
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #ffa500;
  border: 1px solid #e39400;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #e39400;
  border: 1px solid #e39400;
}

.btn-primary:active {
  background-color: #e39400 !important;
  border: 1px solid #e39400 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override the default for Bootstrap, you can change `.btn-primary:active` to:

```
.btn-primary:active {
    background-color: #e39400 !important;
    border: 1px solid #e39400;
}
```